# Special property of circle with radius 0.975399...

Tags: limits, circles, closed-form, infinite-product, arc-length

$4n$ points are uniformly distributed on a circle. Parabolas are drawn in the manner shown below with example $n=4$.

[image]

The parabolas' vertices are at the center of the circle. The parabolas have a common line of symmetry. Each parabola passes through two of the designated points on the circle. (Two parabolas are degenerate and look like lines.)

Call the lengths of the curves $l_1, l_2, l_3, ..., l_{4n}$.

> What is the exact value of the radius $r$, such that $L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{4n} l_k=1$ ?

By experimenting on desmos, it seems that $r\approx0.975399$.

(I believe the number of points does not have to be a multiple of $4$. If it is any even number, then with the above value of $r$, the product of the lengths approaches $1$. But, for the sake of simplicity, I am just asking about the case with $4n$ points.)

**My attempt**

Let $\theta=\dfrac{k\pi}{2n}$. We have

$L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}r^{4n}\left(\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_0^{\cos\theta}\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{2\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}x\right)^2}dx\right)^4$

With some help from [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5B1%2BPower%5B%5C%2840%29ax%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5D%2Cx%5D), and simplifying by taking the 4th root:

$L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}r^{n}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+3\sin^2{\theta}}+\dfrac{\cos\theta}{4\tan\theta}\sinh^{-1}{(2\tan\theta)}\right)=1$

I do not know how to evaluate the product, and I do not know how to find the exact value of $r$.

Context: This is part of a series of investigations I have been doing (just for fun) about infinite products of areas and lengths in a circle. Here are other questions: [question1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4532364/conjecture-about-product-of-lengths-in-a-circle), [question2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4529674/product-of-areas-in-a-circle-why-does-it-approach-1), [question3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4337451/product-of-areas-in-a-circle), [question4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472489/closed-form-for-lim-limits-n-to-infty-prod-limits-k-1n-left2-frac2n2), [question5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4539739/another-interesting-property-of-y-2n-1-prod-k-0n-leftx-cos-frack-pi), [question6](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4536000/what-is-a-closed-form-of-this-limit-product-of-areas-in-circle-with-parabolas).

EDIT: The previous version of this question was about parabolas in a *semicircle*. I mistakenly believed that, if the radius is $0.975399...$ then the product of the lengths approaches $1$. Now I believe that (for the semicircle) the product of the lengths approaches the value of the radius.

Comment: $$r=\exp\left(-\frac2\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\log F(\theta)\,d\theta\right)$$ with $F(\theta)$ the expression under the product. Highly unlikely to have a closed form.